# Clients login and update their personal data in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to create a website with following functions.

Once a users sign in they enter a page with form that has their personal details like weight, blood pressure, last test taken on, next test due on, whether attending etc which they can enter or edit data and a store front where they can buy products.

Can this be possible with wordpress. Is there a plugin, I would buy one if it fulfills my requirement. Please guide me on host requirements also.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Give this plugin a go: http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/

there is also a premium version, but this gives you the basics of what can be done!